# solution for creating "temporary" sortable db table/redis value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, dataset, filtering

I've got a situation where I'm pulling a big data set that needs post processing on the php side for sorting and filtering ( can't all be done in sql ) .  This gets to be extremely slow when a user actually starts to sort or filter the data as we need to run through our nasty sql and post processing logic on each subsequent request.  For arguments sake, let's just say that the sql and post processing is 100% needed as is.  What I'm thinking about doing is creating a 'temporary table' (or something similar) with the data from the first run and then querying the temporary table for all successive sorts/filters.  I'm wondering what people's thoughts may be related to this type of situation.  I don't think a strict mysql temp table will work because those tables are dropped when the connection is dropped and we are not using persistent connections.  I looked into redis but it didn't look like I could do the type of sorting / filtering needed on a set of objects (sorting an associative array on a specific key that could be a number, string, etc. etc.).  Does anybody have any advice on potential solutions for this type of scenario?

I'm using mysql, php, galera cluster

Answer (score 0):

Just `CREATE TABLE` with a "temporary" name, rather than literally `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

If you name them as `__tmp_x` it should be obvious what they are and be easy to clean them up later.

What you're describing sounds like a use-case for a [data warehouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse), though. A deliberately duplicated copy of your database you can thrash around with as aggressively as you want without impacting production. You can export from there as required.